# is there a mobius transformation such that

Tags: functional-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $$f(w) = \sum_{n\ge0} (w-a)^n$$
for every $w \in B(a,1) = \left\{z \in\mathbb C\, :\, |z − a| < 1\right\}$?

I've written until now the equation of Mobius transformation which is
$$w=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ and its inverse 
$$w'=\frac{ab-bc}{(cz+d)^2}$$

How exactly do I show using the equation that the function is a Mobius Transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: your infinite sum is a geometric series. The sum of a geometric series can be written in closed form.